# Getting wrong line numbers and report not reacting to changes with `rollup-plugin-eslint`

Tags: eslint, rollup

I'm consistently getting wrong line numbers on the `eslint` output:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/rollup -c

/Users/asko/Git/es6-trial/src/main.js
   31:7  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 6  indent
   60:7  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 6  indent
   61:7  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 6  indent
  134:7  error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 6  indent
  142:9  error  Expected indentation of 6 space characters but found 8  indent

✖ 5 problems (5 errors, 0 warnings)
```

The reported numbers are one larger than where the problems actually are.

But if I edit the file, the `eslint` output does not change! Is it doing caching of some type?

Unfortunately, the repo where this originates from is not public.

`.eslintrs.json` is:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "impliedStrict": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "assert": false
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 2],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
    // "quotes": ["warn", "single"],
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "warn"
  }
}
```

All of this is weird. Has anyone else, ever, seen this?

---

It has to do with running `eslint` via Rollup. If I run things directly with `./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/*.js`, there is nothing to report.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the *eslint* plugin is configured before the *babel* plugin otherwise linting will run on transpiled code, e.g.:

`plugins: [
    eslint({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    })
  ]`

instead of

`plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    eslint({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    })
  ]`

See https://github.com/TrySound/rollup-plugin-eslint/issues/10

Comment: I posted here the answer to the issue that @akauppi opened on GitHub :-)